# apache wont change listening port

Tags: apache-2.2, port

I edit httpd.conf and add Listen 5900 .
But xampp control panel status displays port 80 when i restart apache. Why it refuses to change port? Which is the correct syntax to edit the httpd file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you have `NameVirtualHost your.ip.here:80` and `<VirtualHost your.ip.here:80>` directives somewhere in your config files, please search for them.

Comment: can't find them

Comment: When you added `Listen 5900` did you delete `Listen 80`? Maybe Apache just listens on two ports, you can check this using `netstat -a -n` or browsing to `http://127.0.0.1:5900`

Comment: ok now apache listens to 5900. but still I cannot have access from another house. Port forwarding is ok set.

Comment: Also, like lampstack, that message is hard-coded into the ctl.sh script.  I believe it's fixed in newer versions.